# Poster - should I send the file to all my collaborators?

Tags: phd, etiquette, poster

I'm a PhD student and I prepared a poster for a conference. Do you think I should send the poster file to all the co-authors? The list is quite long so I mailed the draft only to a few of them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Everybody who is listed as an author should see and be able to contribute to the poster. You wouldn't want to be listed as an author of a work that you have never seen either, right?

Comment: To add to this: If some collaborators trusts you or just do not care, they only need to ignore the mail (if it has a proper subject), which only takes a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with xLeitix's answer:

> Everybody who is listed as an author should see and be able to contribute to the poster.

Also, if it is a big file (assuming your poster is heavy on graphics) perhaps it is best to upload it to dropbox or a similar service and then send the link to all the authors. Depending on their (and your) digital fluency, the team can refine the document right from dropbox without having to send email back and forth.

Comment: On the other hand, having a huge number of people working on something like a poster does not sound like a good idea to me – even with the best version-control system. Let alone the fact that if the OP was considering not even showing the poster to the collaborators, it is likely that they do not want to edit it.

Comment: Also, this should be a comment (which you cannot make, I know).

Comment: I am a bit confused with "This" - are you referring to my comment on the use of dropbox? if so I did agree with xLeitix i.e. people should share. I just wanted to add **how**? If you are referring to @Wrzlprmft's comment I 100% agree with you.